# How to return a Component using the function in react?

Tags: reactjs

I realized that the state value was processed asynchronously during react, so I made a function to process it synchronously and tried to return the component.

This code goes into the handleSearchList function when clicking the icon button, sets the value, synchronizes the state value, and then moves to the Table_Row function and returns a component that meets the condition.

But it doesn't work because I'm react newbie.

Can anyone help me?

```
handleSearchList = () =>{
    
    ...(skip)

    this.setState({ 
        Board_List: search_list,
        Board_list_length: search_list.length
    }, () =>{
        this.Table_Row
    });
}



Table_Row = () => {

    (this.state.Board_rows_per_page > 0
        ? this.state.Board_List.slice(this.state.Board_page * this.state.Board_rows_per_page, this.state.Board_page * this.state.Board_rows_per_page + this.state.Board_rows_per_page)
        : this.state.Board_List
    )
    .map((list) => {

        if (this.state.Board_list_length > 0) {
            return (
                <TableRow hover className="TableRow" key={list.idx} onClick={() => this.handleOpen(list.idx)}>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">{list.rownum}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='20%' align="center">{list.title}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='30%' align="center">{list.content}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">{list.writer}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">{this.caculate_date(list.upd_date)}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">{list.hit}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            );
        }
        else { //웨 안돼
            return (
                <TableRow hover className="TableRow" key="0">
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">adssd</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='20%' align="center">das</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='30%' align="center">adsd</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">ads</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">asdsd</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">asd</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            );
        }
    })
}




return (

    <IconButton onClick={this.handleSearchList} aria-label="search">
        <SearchIcon />
    </IconButton>

     <TableBody >
     {
         this.Table_Row()
     }
     </TableBody>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Table_Row()` should return JSX.

```
Table_Row = () => {

    return (this.state.Board_rows_per_page > 0
        ? this.state.Board_List.slice(this.state.Board_page * this.state.Board_rows_per_page, this.state.Board_page * this.state.Board_rows_per_page + this.state.Board_rows_per_page)
        : this.state.Board_List
    )
    .map((list) => {

        if (this.state.Board_list_length > 0) {
            return (
                <TableRow hover className="TableRow" key={list.idx} onClick={() => this.handleOpen(list.idx)}>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">{list.rownum}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='20%' align="center">{list.title}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='30%' align="center">{list.content}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">{list.writer}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">{this.caculate_date(list.upd_date)}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">{list.hit}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            );
        }
        else { //웨 안돼
            return (
                <TableRow hover className="TableRow" key="0">
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">adssd</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='20%' align="center">das</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='30%' align="center">adsd</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">ads</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='15%' align="center">asdsd</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className="TableCell" width='10%' align="center">asd</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            );
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to render because the return type is an object?